# Insert JSON file into Postgres through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I'm not familiar on how to handle inserting JSON in a Postgres DB in Rails. I saw you can declare a json column type in rails.

I now want to run the command Users.new("Bob", bob) but get the error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

bob = {
      name: "Bob",
      occupation: "Coder",
      pets: [
        name: "Foo",
        type: "dog"
      ]
    }

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.json :data
    end
  end
end
```

In Rails console, I also double checked my table to make sure it's what I expected. So not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
User(id: integer, name: string, data: json)
```

Comment: Have you looked into using a `jsonb` column in your table? May be worth your time. I have found this article very helpful: http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the names of the columns. Try this:

```
Users.new(name: "Bob", data: bob)
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the name of the columns I'm passing my values to.

```
Users.new("Bob", bob)
```

becomes

```
Users.new(name: "Bob", data: bob)
```